# How to store "apollo-fetch" graphql response in a variable?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I created the following code to return the title, forename, and surname from a graphql response. I'm using these returned values to make an automated test that asserts their value:

```
const { createApolloFetch } = require('apollo-fetch');

const uri = 'http://localhost:3000';

const query = `{
    Post(id: 1) {
            id
            title
            forename
            surname
    }
}
`;

const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri });

const returnApolloBody = () => {
    return apolloFetch({query}).
    then(res => res.data)
        .catch(err => {
            throw new Error(err);
        });
};

const responseForename = returnApolloBody().then(result => result.Post.forename);
const responseTitle = returnApolloBody().then(result => result.Post.title);
const responeSurname = returnApolloBody().then(result => result.Post.surname);

module.exports = {
    responseForename: responseForename,
    responseTitle: responseTitle,
    responeSurname: responeSurname,
};
```

However I realised this isn't the most efficient way, as I'm amking a separate http request for each value. I thought it would be much easier to store the entire response as a JSON value, and then extract the values from this variable, however I'm not having much luck. I have the following code, and the values are returned as undefined:

```
const { createApolloFetch } = require('apollo-fetch');

const uri = 'http://localhost:3000';

const query = `{
    Post(id: 1) {
            id
            title
            forename
            surname
    }
}
`;

const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri });

const returnApolloBody = () => {
    return apolloFetch({query}).
    then(res => res)
        .catch(err => {
            throw new Error(err);
        });
};

const response = returnApolloBody().then(response => response);

const forename = response.then(response => response.Post.forename);
const surname = response.then(response => response.Post.surname);
const title = response.then(response => response.Post.title);


module.exports = {
    forename: forename,
    title: title,
    surname: surname
};
```

What am I missing to allow me to store the entire response in a const, and then query specific properties in that const?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to return result `response.Post` as object, e.g. below I am using apolloclient to fetch user profile

```
apolloclient.query({
query: q_my_profile}).then(
resp => {
    resolve(resp.data.my_profile);
},
error => {
    reject(error.message);
});
```